# gganimate within Shiny app - cannot find ImageMagick

Tags: r, shiny, imagemagick, shinyapps, gganimate

I would like to insert animation plot in my Shiny app published on the server. However, any try of deploying ends up in the following:

> I cannot find ImageMagick with convert = 'convert'
>   Warning in im.convert(img.files, output = path.expand(movie.name), convert = 
>   convert,  :
>   Please install ImageMagick first or put its bin path into the system PATH variable

Of course, there is no problem when I run the application on my computer with installed imageMagick. So my question is how can I force Shiny server to use the imageMagick from my computer or install it in Shiny environment?

Comment: `ssh` into the server and install every package your apps are using from the commandline (e.g: `Rscript -e "install.packages(c('package_A', 'package_B'))")`

Comment: @GyD, any chance to elaborate on that? I am totally new Shiny user (this is supposed to be my first app) and can't make use of your hint. The designed server is the default - shinyapps.io, if that matters.

Comment: Perhaps you need to install ImageMagick. If you installed ImageMagick 7, then `magick` replaces `convert`. You should make sure whichever version of ImageMagick is compatible with your other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the `magick` library:

See the vignette for an example making explicit reference to using `magick` with `gganimate`:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#animation

On GitHub, There is also an example map showing successful use of `magick` on Shinyapps.io:

https://github.com/jeroen/shinymagick